# vsixmanifest migrate v1.0 to v2.0

Tags: visual-studio, templates, migration, vsix, vsixmanifest

I have a vsix manifest in version 1.0 as used in VS2010 and I want to migrate it to vsix manifest version 2.0.

The version 1.0 looks like:

```
<Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010">
  <Identifier Id="38cd15a6-54db-4372-bf21-42e77038a3c5">
    <Name>INProcessor</Name>
    <Author>Info</Author>
    :
```

The version 2.0 looks like:

```
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema-design/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="INProcessor.Company.d19aa80e-a7e4-4508-a6c3-9a3518bb153b" Version="1.0" Language="en-US" Publisher="Company" />
    <DisplayName>INProcessor</DisplayName>
    :
```

I tried to migrate by loading it in a newer VisualStudio version than 2010. But the vsix-file is not migrated into the newer format. If I open it with the vsix manifest editor, it only shows the xml source code.

Is there any way to migrate vsix manifest files automatically ?

I also searched the internet for more descriptions about the xml tags in version 1.0 and version 2.0, but I could not find any useful information.
Do you know any information somewhere, so that I can do the migration manually ?

Thank you
Kind regards,
Tom